# get_template_part() not working with Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I work on the WordPress project I created testimonials in a special file called testimonials.php and I called the file on the page about us by get_template_part and it works fine but when I called (testimonials.php) to the home page not show all values.

Use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin

```
<!-- Start Section Testimonials -->
<section class="testimonials section-padding">
<div class="carousel-right col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <?php $testimonials = array ('post_type' => 'Testimonials' , 'order' => 'ASC');
            $query = new wp_query($testimonials);
                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                while ($query->have_posts()){
                    $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <!-- Start Item 1 -->
                        <div class="testimonials-item">
                            <!-- Testimonials Text -->
                            <div class="testimonials-text-item">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Testimonials Title -->
                            <div class="testimonials-title clearfix">
                                <!-- Title Img -->
                                <div class="title-img">
                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="testimonials">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Title Text -->
                                <div class="title-text">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <p><?php the_field('small_title'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Item 1 -->
                    <?php }} ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<!-- Start Title -->
<?php $testimonials = get_field('testimonials'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="testimonials-text clearfix">
                <div class="title">
                    <span><?php echo $testimonials['small_title']; ?></span>
                    <h2><?php echo $testimonials['main_title']; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="text-p">
                <?php echo $testimonials['description']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Title -->
</section>
```

The part that does not appear from all values

```
<span> <? php echo $ testimonials ['small_title']; ?> </ span>
<h2> <? php echo $ testimonials ['main_title']; ?> </ h2>
<? php echo $ testimonials ['description']; ?>
```

Comment: Do they use group values ?

Answer (score 0):

as you use multiple $testimonials i suppose those are group values.

then you need to use `get_sub_field()` in place of `get_field()`

so it should look like

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$testimonials = get_sub_field('testimonials',$term);
echo $testimonials['small_title'];
echo $testimonials['main_title'];
echo $testimonials['description'];
```

Please refer to ACF documentation when you use non classical fields.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/

Comment: Unfortunately, the values also did not show

Comment: i edited my answear with adding queried object.